# How to generate a unique reference ID of at most 10 characters for a financial transaction in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, database, key, uuid

I want to create a unique key for a transaction done by a particular user of my Android app at a particular time. I have read about two ways of doing this:

1. Concatenating the current timestamp with the user id or user's device id
2. Using Java's UUID class for generating a unique string for each transaction

I have a couple of concerns with the resultant strings from these methods:

1. The result of first method could probably be too obvious for users to guess and access others' transactions
2. The results of both methods appear to be too long to communicate to the users

Does anyone know of a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why are they too long? What is your max size? I would simply randomize over the ASCII table, using a timestamp and userId concatenation to seed the results.

Comment: Hi Robin, the user key is a 16 digit long number and timestamp adds another 13 digits. To save (on the server) and communicate (to ths users) such a long transaction reference number would be a pain, right?

Comment: Not really, we are talking about a few bytes. In any case, if you want to shorten it, you can use whatever rule you want. For example you could use the last 5 digits from the timestamp and one out of every two digits on the userId. Moreover, you could create your key as specified, then salt and hash (or anything that is deterministic) it so it is smaller.

Comment: I can remove the milliseconds from the timestamp, but if I take alternate digits, wouldn't it make a collision likely? I am not too familiar with hashing, but would reducing the length of the key through hashing also leave a chance for a key collision?

Comment: For whatever the format you use, the longer the key, the less chance of collision there can be. So as you shorten your key, it *will* increase the chances of collision. 

I'm not going to go into the maths behind this, but all in all if you want keep the entropy level down on this, you should use the biggest key possible.

I would rather send a large key with little chance of collision rather than a small key with large chances of collision.

Comment: Weigh the costs: if you are adding a few bytes to all of your transmissions, but dividing by 10 the number of transactions that collide, it is probably worth it. Doubly so in the case of financial transactions.

Comment: You're right, but isn't having 29 digits for a transaction id a bit too much? I haven't seen such long ids anywhere. I mean, what if a user wanted to quote a particular transaction id over phone?

Comment: Yea 29 digits seems a bit long to me. Just take the (N)th and (N+2)th digit, then 5 last digits from the timestamp (that should lower its size while not reducing its entropy *too much*), then concatenante with a *salted* userId. That would keep it at around 15 characters.

Comment: Wait nevermind: these ids should not be human readable nor should they be *sent over the phone*. You wanna make another transaction Id for Ids that need to be human-readable. We are mostly talking about authenticating a phone to server or server to phone transaction, where machines talk to machines right?

Comment: Yup, you're right. I should have two separate ids - one for the backend authentication and one for communicating to the user

Comment: Yes, with the machine Ids having a full length, and nice entropy (with almost no collisions) and the Front-Facing ids are smaller, have a worst entropy, but are easy for humans to transmit. I would put a timeout on the second id's validity, to counteract its weakness. Generate them, but make them active only for 1 minute or something. That gives you security without compromising on key length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use what you are suggesting as your transaction identifiers when making transactions between your app and your server (machines talking to machines). 29 characters isn't that much for a transaction key, especially with the kind of connections smartphones have today.

**I would salt those values though just to add a little obfuscation.**

After that, for your transaction ids that need to be sent from/to humans, you are going to want something smaller (more tolerable and human-readable). I would use smaller ids (which can collide) but make them work only for a certain amount of time.

See my comments for more information.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks so much Robin! For the user-facing ids, what about having just a simple id that identifies a transaction uniquely for a given user but not a unique transaction globally?

Comment: Actually I think you'd lose security on that. How about generating a new TransactionId (long), then hashing it down for size or readability? You can then make sure it is only valid for a certain time to get that security back (that you lost by hashing). This is all very approximate and depends on a lot of factors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ISBN13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number#ISBN-13_check_digit_calculation). Easy to calculate and the code space is about 2^40. If you concat to ISBNs you can reach a code space above 2^80.

Comment: Could you please clarify how ISBN13 would work in my case? Thanks!